# How to store each line in a file in a separate array?

Tags: python, arrays, file

I have a file whose contents are as below:

```
3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17
17 15 13 11 9 7 5 3
3 5 7 9 8 7 6 5
17 15 13 11 12 13 14 15
```

I want to store it in 4 different array, one array for each line, e.g.

```
arr1=[3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17]
arr2=[17 15 13 11 9 7 5 3]
arr3=[3 5 7 9 8 7 6 5], and
arr4=[17 15 13 11 12 13 14 15]
```

Comment: Those arrays you want to get is not even a valid Python code. By the way, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Okay, so what happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can try using python context manager to read your file and then assign the variables

```
with open(file name, 'r') as f:
    arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4= [x.replace('\n'.'') for x in f.readlines()]
```

Comment: Thanks.Is there a way to use the loop for assigning it to different arrays.Because there can be any number of lines and it should create n number of arrays as well

Comment: @Ratzet In that case, you might be better off using a dictionary (with each line as values for each key).

Comment: Yes, the best way to do it is using dictionary but the problem statement as part of my assignment strictly says to not use the dictionary and thats where it becomes tricky.